# How do you deal with rejected responses in guzzel?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, guzzle6

Consider the following code:

```
public function getItemHistoryForRegion(array $items, array $regions) {

    $client            = new Client(['expect' => false]);
    $acceptedResponses = [];
    $rejectedResponses = [];
    $createdRequests   = [];
    $regionAndItem     = [];

    foreach($items as $item) {
        foreach ($regions as $region) {
            array_push($regionAndItem, [$item, $region]);
            array_push($createdRequests, new Request('GET', 'https://public-crest.eveonline.com/market/'.$region.'/types/'.$item.'/history/'));
        }
    }

    $pool = new Pool($client, $createdRequests, [
        'concurrency' => 10,
        'fulfilled'   => function ($response, $index) use (&$acceptedResponses) {
            EveLogHandler::requestLog($response, 'eve_online_region_item_history_responses.log');
            $acceptedResponses[$index] = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
        },
        'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$rejectedResponses)  {
            EveLogHandler::messageLog($reason, 'eve_online_region_item_history_rejected_responses.log');
        },
    ]);

    $promise = $pool->promise();
    $promise->wait();

    $historyDetails = new HistoryDetails($acceptedResponses, $regionAndItem);
    $historyDetails->createHistoryDetails();

    return $historyDetails->getHistoryDetails();
}
```

I create a an array of requests that are then pooled. There are generally 10,000 requests that come through here.

One of the issues is the rejected section:

```
'rejected'    => function ($reason, $index) use(&$rejectedResponses)  {
                EveLogHandler::messageLog($reason, 'eve_online_region_item_history_rejected_responses.log');
},
```

Here I just log out the rejected message and it comes back as:

```
[2016-01-27 16:35:00] production.INFO: Message ["[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /home/ccccc/test_site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186)"] []
[2016-01-27 16:35:57] production.INFO: Message ["[object] (GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ConnectException(code: 0): cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) at /home/ccccc/test_site/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186)"] []
```

Theres a ton of these as there are probably well over 13 jobs that get queued that each send 10,000 requests each, as you can see I pool them so I do 10 at a time.

The rate limit for this api is 150 requests per second. So I know I am not hitting a 150 or at least I shouldn't be.

**The question I have for you is how do I re-try the rejected request? Is there a way to say, on fail retry a max of x times? Does guzzle have that built in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl error that you are receiving might be an indication of the server / proxy / firewall rate limiting you; especially if your application is throwing 10k requests at it.  The error itself (at least according to [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) indicates that your application is not receiving a response.

I believe you would be looking for either "retry middleware" or a "rate limiting middleware"

Comment: They use a 503 if I hit the rate limit, I am doing 18-20 concurrent connections which they allow, I do 100 a time instead of 10k (I chunk the 10k into 100)